# include function xy() of a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, class, function, include

I want to build a WordPress admin dashboard widget which should return some information from another plugin.

This dashboard widget should read the functions of this plugin here:
http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-document-revisions/trunk/wp-document-revisions.php

So my code is:

```
include (WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/wp-document-revisions/wp-document-revisions.php');
$file_type = get_file_type('3');
```

But this doesn't work. These are the errors:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in
>   /.../wp-content/plugins/wp-document-revisions/wp-document-revisions.php
>   on line 26
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_file_type() in
>   /.../wp-content/plugins/dashboard-widget/dashboard-widget.php

Can anyone tell me how I have to do this, that I can read the function get_file_type('3')?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are navigating straight to your PHP file in the wp-content/plugins/ folder rather than using a stub to create a URL. If this is the case, then you probably forgot to include wp-load.php

Comment: add_action() is a WordPress core function, so if that function doesn't exist it means you haven't actually loaded WordPress. You could do `include('../../../wp-load.php');` (or whatever points to your wp-load.php file) and you should then be able to use functions from any active plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You should not include the plugin file (since the plugin may not be installed or activated).
Instead of this you should check if the function exists:

```
if (function_exists('get_file_type')) {
 $file_type = get_file_type('3'); 
 // rest of the code of the widget
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to access the PHP file directly, rather than going through WordPress proper. You should create a plugin, and hook into the [Dashboard Widgets API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API).

As for implementation with WP Document Revisions, you've got two options. As of version 1.2, `get_documents()` and `get_document_revisions()` are two global functions that will be accessible anytime after the `plugins_loaded` hook. The [FAQ](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-document-revisions/faq/) has a bit more info, but they basically function like the native `get_posts()` function.

Alternatively, the class should be available globally as `$wpdr`. So if you wanted, for example, to call `get_latest_version( 1 )` it'd be `$wpdb->get_latest_version( 1 )`.

Both assume the plugin's already activated. If you simply include the file, you're going to get an error that you're trying to redeclare the `WP_Document_Revisions` class.

If you do create a dashboard, I'd love to include it in future releases of the plugin!